# Why don't we get compile-time error for casting here?

Tags: java, casting

In the following example, why does the compiler not report an error for casting `x` to `D`?

```java
interface X {}
class C implements X {}
class D {}

public class CastIssue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new C();

        // why is there no error here?
        D d = (D) x;
    }
}
```

But, if we make `X` a class, the compiler reports an error:

```java
class X {}
class C extends X {}
class D {}

public class CastIssue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new C();

        // this gives a compile-time error
        D d = (D) x;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get a ClassCastException at runtime for any other value than null.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's incorrect. You have compiler-time casting errors and those that will not occur until runtime. See the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting from `X` to `D` is allowed because it's possible for an object to be an instance of both `X` and `D`. For example:

```java
class E extends D implements X {}
X x = new E();
D d = (D) x; // no problem here, because an X can be a D too
```

In your example, we can determine from the sequence of statements that the cast *will* fail, but Java cannot, because it does not consider the flow of control when determining types at compile-time.

However, if `X` is a class, then because `X` and `D` would have no common subclasses (Java does not allow multiple inheritance for classes), it would be impossible for an object to be an instance of both unrelated classes. In that case, the cast is not allowed because based on the compile-time types, the cast could never succeed (unless `x` is `null`).

Comment: Thanks @kaya3 for detailed explanation.